# QGIS animation help ancestral records

Tags: qgis, animation, timemanager

I only have basic GIS skills and wanted some advice or direction.

I'm only practising with a smaller dataset at the moment though my other files are much larger 10,000+ so don't know if it's possible or if I would have to separate the data by years.

Essentially I have a CSV file with the names of ancestors name, birth year, birth location, mother, father, and the coordinates of the birth location.

I wanted to create a time series / animation of their chronological birth order. I've got them in a basic map at the moment on QGIS as that is all I have access to (I don't know if that makes a difference) and span across America and Europe.

I had a look at TIME MANAGER but that seems outdated (I couldn't install it) and read that the plugin temporal profile may be good for this, however I need to convert my CSV file to a raster I believe, but I cannot understand how the rasterize would work on my CSV file because it requires output extent (I don't understand what this is) I had a look at my file and it states 0,0,0,0.

Am I going about this the right way or am I completely off track. Also I've seen people do this on YouTube with time manager but with times, can I do this just with years?

Comment: 1) You question needs more focus 2) You don't need a raster for Temporal controller, works perfect with vectors (points) 3) If you have only a year, you could convert (create a field) in datetime format an assign an arbitrary date, say 1st of Jan. or 30st of June of each year. 4) Whatch out for `qgis temporal controller`, there are quite some tutorials out there - a nice one is this here: https://youtu.be/vgDg5cRwPRw

Comment: oh okay I will have a look at that next, thank you